# How to add srcObject attribute of video tag and dynamically insert that to html page using java script,jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

[media stream object inside console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMOow.png) and this is [what i'm getting after setting source attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0M1i.png)This is the function at clientside script,I'm using webrtc to do a project and below function is called when i want to add stream.Each time the function is called i must be able to add a new stream to a new video tag dynamically into my html page

```
function handleRemoteStreamAdded() {
    console.log('Remote stream added.',event);
    remoteStream=event.stream;
    var vid=jQuery('<video autoplay></video>');
    vid.srcObject=remoteStream;

    jQuery('#videos').append(vid);
}
```

This is client html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="videos"></div>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/libs/mustache.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is not working it injects the video tag but its not assigning source. I'm unable to see the video.

[image]

Comment: try `vid.attr('src', remoteStream);` instead of `vid.srcObject=remoteStream;`

Comment: [object%20MediaStream]:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) this is showing up in console

Comment: [object%20MediaStream]:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) is showing up in console

Comment: We really need to know what the event object looks like.

Comment: sir i've added the snapshot please look into it

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I think I am facing the same issue. It used to work, but not anymore...

Comment: yes it can be solved by setting    vid.autoplay=true;

Comment: @kirankulangara Hi, same time of year and I'm dealing with exactly the same issue. Actually I just tested, if I use JS instead of jQuery it works fine, but when I add the code to select the element thru jquery I cannot assign the src object. Can you tell me what do you mean by setting autoplay to true? I already did that in HTML as shown in all webrtc examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are probaly confused with

```
vid.src = '';
```

However, in this case its an JavaScript object. But you are using jQuery, so you should use jQuery's [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to add an attribute.

```
vid.attr('src', remoteStream);
```

Some more errors are present in your script.

---

```
console.log('Remote stream added.', event);
```

What is the `event`? You never define that variable or pass it as
variable through the function.

---

```
remoteStream = event.stream;
```

This should be (if using `use strict`).

```
var remoteStream = event.stream;
```

Doens't matter in its current form though, as it will be still *undefined* if `event` is an unknown variable.

Comment: event is acquired inside the function without defining. its actually a webrtc event.This is working properly if i specify video tags by id and select it using document query selector, and setting its srcObject....But in my use case i can't perdict the no of video tags required ..actually i'm streaming videos from multiple cameras to single page....i don't know much about java script and jquery ...please suggest some way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on comments:

```js
//get the html element that holds all videos
var videoContainer = $('#videos');

//assuming the "source object" mentioned will look something like this
var sourceObject1 = jQuery('<source/>', {
  class: 'video-stream',
  src: 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
});
// or a stringified version
var sourceObject2 = '<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">'

function addVideo(srcObject) {
  //create a <video> element inside videos html element
  var videoElement = jQuery('<video/>', {
    class: 'video-stream'
  }).appendTo(videoContainer);
  //add the "source object" to the new <video> element
  videoElement.append(srcObject);
}


addVideo(sourceObject1);
addVideo(sourceObject2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videos"></div>
```

Comment: i'm not getting a url...i'm getting a source object so how to add this source object to video tag to get the stream

Comment: Gotcha. What does the source object look like?

Comment: I have updated the answer.  If it doesn't work please post a screenshot of the "source object" in the debugger.

Comment: sir i don't have a url....all i have is a media stream object ...i'll post the pic

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old however none of the answers seem to work.

The way to assign a [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) object to a `<video>` element using JQuery is:

```js
$videoElement.prop('srcObject', mediaStream);
```